# Laravel : Getting memory error while sending mail (Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted)

Tags: php, laravel, memory, sendmail

I am very new to PHP/LARAVEL development trying to develop 1 application to send the email from smtp.gmail.com.

I am getting error as

> [ [Tue Jan 11 17:11:32.765352 2022] [php:error] [pid 21752:tid 1952] [client ::1:56549] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 132124672 bytes) ]

in below line of code:

```
try {
      Mail::to($user->email)->send(new SendMail($message1,$notification_template->subject));
} 
catch (\Throwable $th) {
      throw $th;
}
```

I already tried to set `memory_limit` to `-1`(no limit) or `2048M` in `php.ini`, but no luck. Getting same error from XAMPP and VSCode.

I am using gmail as SMTP server for sending email.

Can you please help me to understand the issue and to fix it?

Comment: Is this in a loop? You're too minimal here for us to help, likely issue is elsewhere.

Comment: This is not in loop. But when i comment //throw $th, it redirect the users to desired page although mail is not sent (sendmail block might be sending in catch block).   When i uncomment throw $th, this prints the error in log and throws the exception.

Comment: Why are you throwing something that you just caught? The best thing to do in that section is to log what the issue is, and return a message to the user.

Comment: When you changed the memory limit, did you restart the PHP process?

Answer (score 0):

> change in following file this will solve your problem:

```
File: /etc/php.ini

memory_limit = 512M;
```